# What is happening at the particle level in the Bernoulli Principle?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

One might think that increasing the speed of particles would increase pressure -- if I understand what the Principle states, it is very counterintuitive.

My guess is, the pressure has something to do with particles moving perpendicular to the fast motion and maybe the particles spend less time hitting the sides of the pipe but there are also more particles per unit time.

I have some other ideas but the above guess is the kind of explanation I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The particles, on average, keep their energy, but the motion becomes more organized. They have more velocity along the streamlines, and less toward the sides.

Comment: What causes the side-to-side motion to diminish?

Comment: "What causes the side-to-side motion to diminish?" Conservation of energy, as John Doty said.

Answer (score 1):

The Bernoulli principle comes from the second law of Newton. If we take a slice of fluid with cross section $A$ of a horizontal pipe, and with length $\Delta x$, the net force acting on it is:$$\Delta F = -\Delta P A$$ The minus sign indicates that the pressure must be decreasing along $x$, for a positive force on the slice. The mass is $\Delta m = \rho A \Delta x = \rho A v \Delta t$. The acceleration of the slice is $a = \frac{dv}{dt}$. When the deltas go to zero, $$dF = (dm) a \implies -dpA = \rho A v dv \implies -dP = d\left(\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2\right)$$
That means: an increase in velocity requires a decrease of pressure if the density is constant.

By the way, it has nothing to do with movement of particles, at least for liquids. The pressure is related to the repulsion of the electronic shell of the molecules.